# how to copy contents from one textbox in one form to another textbox in another form through JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text, copy

```
<form action="formoneaction" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="t1" />
  <button type="sumbit" class="btn">Insert</button>
</form>

<form action="formtwoaction" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="t2" />
  <button type="sumbit" class="btn">Insert</button>
</form>

<script>
    var t1 = document.getElementById('t1');
    t1.onkeyup = t1.onchange = function() {
      document.getElementById('t2').value = this.value;
    };
</script>
```

How can I get the script to work when the two elements are in separate forms? The script works when none of them are in forms.

I've never learned JS before so I may not understand very well when someone explains a bunch of jargon. Sorry but I'll try my best!

Comment: Your code is working fine.. what else you need

Comment: what it means, *another form*?

Comment: This script does not work with textarea for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out below Code, which copies data from `textbox` to `TextArea`:

```
$("#textArea").append("\n * " + $("#textBox").val());
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/qy7rT/125/)